# Intersection of array with select statement in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to do an intersect of a select statement with an array that is dynamically computed in a loop and then measure the time taken for each of those intersect queries.

So in the first iteration of the loop, I want the query to be like this:

```
'select sub_id from table where main_id=1 INTERSECT select array[''80'']';
```

In the second iteration:

```
'select sub_id from table where main_id=1 INTERSECT select array[''80'', ''81'']';
```

and so on and measure the time taken in each of those iterations to execute the query.

When I run this script, I get the error:

> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block at assignment

which corresponds to the line where I initialize query1. How do I correct the assignment to the query1? I am using PostgreSQL 9.1.

```
arr := '{}';
for j in 80..120 loop
  arr := array_append(arr, j::text);
  query1 := 'select sub_id from table where main_id=1 INTERSECT' || ' select unnest(arr)';
  execute 'explain (analyse, format json) ' || query1 into p;
  t := (p->0->>'Planning Time')::float + (p->0->>'Execution Time')::float;
  total_time := total_time + t;
end loop;
```

Comment: That's not the error.  THat's debug info. The error is probably on the preceding line in the logs or output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query text you `execute` can't reference variables from the calling scope. You have to pass the variable as a parameter with `using` like:

```
query1 := 'select sub_id from YourTable where main_id=1 INTERSECT select unnest($1)';
execute 'explain (analyse, format json) ' || query1 using arr into p;
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

[Working example at rextester.com](http://rextester.com/RQBA13164)